# Echo full array from sql

Tags: php

Am trying to get data from SQL that match a specific word so I wrote this code for it

```
<?php 
        require ('config.php');
        $searchphrase = $_GET['seach'];
        $searcharry =  explode(" ", $searchphrase);
        $searcharrycount = count($searcharry);
        $i1 = 0;
        $i2 = 0;    
        //sql
        while ( $i1 < $searcharrycount) {
        $sql = "SELECT word, url FROM words WHERE word LIKE '%$searcharry[$i1]%'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $url = explode(" , ", $row["url"]);
                    $urlcount = count($url);
                    while ($i2<$urlcount) {
                        echo $url[$i2]."<br>";
                        $i2++;
                    }
                }   
            } 
            $i1++;

        }

        //end sql
        $conn->close();

         ?>
```

and this is how my SQL is designed

[image: SQL data structure]

So when I run this code I expect to get results like the flowing
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six

However, I get the flowing results when I run the code:
One
Two
Five
Six

So my question is how can I show the output that I expect rather than showing two of every row in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never reset `$i2`, so as you process more rows of database results, `$i2` keeps growing, and you eventually start using indexes that DON'T EXIST. E.g. let's say ever row of your DB contains `3` urls.

```
row1: url1,url2,url3
row2: url4,url5,url6
row3: url7,url8,url9
etc...
```

Since you never reset `$i2`, you end up doing:

```
row1: url1,url2,url3
  i2    0   1     2

row2: url4,url5,url6
  i2:                 3   4   5

row3: url7,url8,url9
  i2:                             6   7   8
```

Either put a `$i2=0` before your `while()` loop, so you always start with index `0`, or simply get rid of that (pointless) while loop entirely:

```
echo str_replace(' , ', '<br>', $row['url']);
```

Since all you're doing, really, is changing that comma to a break, might as well change ALL of them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Set `$i2` to zero in every iteration of `while` loop:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $url = explode(" , ", $row["url"]);
    $urlcount = count($url);
    $i2 = 0;          // reset $i2 here
    while ($i2<$urlcount) {
        echo $url[$i2]."<br>";
        $i2++;
    }
}
```